# how can i get Exprs of julia code accoring to function and argtypes？

Tags: julia, expr

i am new in Julia. i read a doc about julia static-analysis. it gives a function.

```
function foo(x,y)
  z = x + y
  return 2 * z
end
```

and use the julia introspection function code_typed get output:

```
code_typed(foo,(Int64,Int64))

1-element Array{Any,1}:
:($(Expr(:lambda, {:x,:y}, {{:z},{{:x,Int64,0},{:y,Int64,0},{:z,Int64,18}},{}},
 :(begin  # none, line 2:
        z = (top(box))(Int64,(top(add_int))(x::Int64,y::Int64))::Int64 # line 3:
        return (top(box))(Int64,(top(mul_int))(2,z::Int64))::Int64
    end::Int64))))
```

it has an Expr . but when i call code_typed, the output is :

```
code_typed(foo, (Int64,Int64))

1-element Vector{Any}:
 CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Base.add_int(x, y)::Int64
│   %2 = Base.mul_int(2, %1)::Int64
└──      return %2
) => Int64
```

it has a CodeInfo.it is different with the output in doc.

does julia have some change? and how can i get the Exprs according to my function and argtypes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code snippet appears to be taken from https://www.aosabook.org/en/500L/static-analysis.html, which was published in 2016 (about two years before the release of Julia 1.0) and references Julia version 0.3 from 2015.

Julia 1.0 gives

```
julia> code_typed(foo,(Int64,Int64))
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 CodeInfo(
2 1 ─ %1 = (Base.add_int)(x, y)::Int64                                   │╻ +
3 │   %2 = (Base.mul_int)(2, %1)::Int64                                  │╻ *
  └──      return %2                                                     │ 
) => Int64
```

while more current versions such as 1.6 and 1.7 give

```
julia> code_typed(foo,(Int64,Int64))
1-element Vector{Any}:
 CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Base.add_int(x, y)::Int64
│   %2 = Base.mul_int(2, %1)::Int64
└──      return %2
) => Int64
```

(a much more minor change, but nonetheless)

If for any reason, you want this result in the form of an array or vector of `Expr`s, you seem to be able to get this using (e.g.)

```
julia> t = code_typed(foo,(Int64,Int64));

julia> t[1].first.code
3-element Vector{Any}:
 :(Base.add_int(_2, _3))
 :(Base.mul_int(2, %1))
 :(return %2)
```

though this is likely considered an implementation detail and liable to change between minor versions of Julia.